# What is this DESHashSessionKeyBackward file in WOW6432Node/Microsoft/Cryptography and what it is do?

Tags: windows, file, cryptography

Unfortunately, it was not possible to find information on the network, all links bring to articles about ransomwares.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34199 perhaps?